# How do I print to the default printer on my Laptop from a VB.NET app I deployed to a IIS 8 server?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, printing, iis-8

I've developed a VB.Net App using Visual studio 2015 on my Laptop which will print a rdlc local report for each selected row from a Gridview control directly to my laptop's default printer (which is a network printer) using the Microsoft code for 'walkthrough: Printing a Local Report without Preview' (and runs successfully on my local IIS express).  When I deploy this App to a virtual company windows 2012 server that has IIS8 running, it no longer sees the default printer on my laptop (and tries to use the default printer on the windows 2012 server). I've searched the web to no success.  I assume it's possible because when I use the reportviewer control in other apps I've developed and deployed on the Windows 2012 server, it can see the list of printers from my local laptop. Any ideas?

Here's the relevant VB code I'm using now...

```
Imports System.Management
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms


Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Implements IDisposable
Private m_currentPageIndex As Integer
Private m_streams As IList(Of Stream)
Public Shared ViewID As String
Public Shared UserID As String
Public Shared StampID As String
Public Shared GridViewQry As String
Public Shared OpenCntr As Integer = 0

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim sqlConnection2 As New SqlConnection("DataSource=AOXWEBAPP1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ManufacturingApps;User ID=AppUser;Password=@ppus3r;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite")
    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1))
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore()

    OpenCntr = OpenCntr + 1
    ViewID = Request.QueryString("ViewID")
    If ViewID = "" Then
        Response.Redirect("http://AOXWEBAPP1.SCOTT.COM/login/login.aspx")
    Else
        UserID = Request.QueryString("UserID")
        StampID = Request.QueryString("StampID")
    End If
    cmd2.CommandText = "UpDate Super_FinalChk SET Selected=1 WHERE Printed = 1"
    cmd2.Connection = sqlConnection2
    sqlConnection2.Open()
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlConnection2.Close()
    If OpenCntr = 1 Then
        GridViewQry = "SELECT [Printed], [Customer], [AssySN], [Dte], [AssyPartNbr], [Operator], [PrintDate] FROM [Super_FinalChk] ORDER BY [Dte]"
    End If
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(GridViewQry, sqlConnection2)
    Dim superfinalchk As New DataSet("SqlDataSource1")
    adapter.Fill(superfinalchk, "Super_FinalChkVw")
    If (superfinalchk.Tables.Count > 0) Then
        PrintATRs.DataSource = superfinalchk
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            PrintATRs.DataBind()
        End If
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "Unable to Connect to Database"
    End If
    '        TextBox1.Text = DefaultPrinterName()
End Sub

' Routine to provide to the report renderer, in order to
' save an image for each page of the report.
Private Function CreateStream(ByVal name As String, ByVal fileNameExtension As String, ByVal encoding As Encoding, ByVal mimeType As String, ByVal willSeek As Boolean) As Stream
    Dim stream As Stream = New MemoryStream()
    m_streams.Add(stream)
    Return stream
End Function

' Export the given report as an EMF (Enhanced Metafile) file.
Private Sub Export(ByVal report As LocalReport)
    Dim deviceInfo As String = "<DeviceInfo>" &
        "<OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>" &
        "<PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" &
        "<PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" &
        "<MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>" &
        "<MarginLeft>0.50in</MarginLeft>" &
        "<MarginRight>0.50in</MarginRight>" &
        "<MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>" &
        "</DeviceInfo>"
    Dim warnings As Warning()
    m_streams = New List(Of Stream)()
    report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, AddressOf CreateStream, warnings)
    For Each stream As Stream In m_streams
        stream.Position = 0
    Next
End Sub
' Handler for PrintPageEvents

Private Sub PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal ev As PrintPageEventArgs)
    Dim pageImage As New Metafile(m_streams(m_currentPageIndex))

    ' Adjust rectangular area with printer margins.
    Dim adjustedRect As New Rectangle(ev.PageBounds.Left - CInt(ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX),
                                      ev.PageBounds.Top - CInt(ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY),
                                      ev.PageBounds.Width,
                                      ev.PageBounds.Height)

    ' Draw a white background for the report
    ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect)

    ' Draw the report content
    ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect)

    ' Prepare for the next page. Make sure we haven't hit the end.
    m_currentPageIndex += 1
    ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count)
End Sub

Private Sub PrintRep()
    If m_streams Is Nothing OrElse m_streams.Count = 0 Then
        Throw New Exception("Error: no stream to print.")
    End If
    Dim printDoc As New PrintDocument()
    If Not printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid Then
**
It FAILS HERE!!!!
**
        Throw New Exception("Error: cannot find the printer.")
    Else
        AddHandler printDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintPage
        m_currentPageIndex = 0
        printDoc.Print()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    If m_streams IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each stream As Stream In m_streams
            stream.Close()
        Next
        m_streams = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Function LoadSuperFinalChkVwData(AssySN As String) As DataTable
    Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=AOXWEBAPP1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ManufacturingApps;User ID=AppUser;Password=@ppus3r;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite")
    Dim querystring As String = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Super_FinalChkVw WHERE AssySN = '" & AssySN & "'"
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(querystring, sqlConnection1)

    Dim superfinalchkvw As New DataSet("DataSet1")
    adapter.Fill(superfinalchkvw, "Super_FinalChkVw")
    Return superfinalchkvw.Tables(0)
End Function


Protected Sub Print_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Print.Click
    Dim report As New LocalReport()
    Dim sqlConnection2 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=AOXWEBAPP1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ManufacturingApps;User ID=AppUser;Password=@ppus3r;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite")
    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand
    Dim cudate As DateTime
    Dim AssySN As String
    Dim cntr As Integer = 0
    Dim SelectCount As Integer = 0


    cudate = DateTime.Now
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cudate", cudate)
    For Each row As GridViewRow In PrintATRs.Rows
        cntr = cntr + 1
        Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("checkbox3"), CheckBox)
        AssySN = row.Cells(3).Text
        If cb.Checked Then
            SelectCount = SelectCount + 1
            report.ReportPath = "..\..\Manufacture\Superiox\ATR.rdlc"
            report.DataSources.Clear()
            report.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", LoadSuperFinalChkVwData(AssySN)))
            Export(report)
            PrintRep()
            cmd2.CommandText = "UpDate Super_FinalChk SET Selected=0, Printed=1, PrintDate=@cudate  WHERE AssySN = '" & AssySN & "';"
            cmd2.Connection = sqlConnection2
            sqlConnection2.Open()
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlConnection2.Close()
        End If
    Next
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(GridViewQry, sqlConnection2)
    Dim superfinalchk As New DataSet("SqlDataSource1")
    adapter.Fill(superfinalchk, "Super_FinalChkVw")
    PrintATRs.DataSource = superfinalchk
    PrintATRs.DataBind()
    If SelectCount > 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = "Reports Have Been Printed!"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "Please Select Reports to Print!"
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: The short answer is, you can't. You will always need something in the middle. Think about it. If what you wanted was possible, making a web server somewhere out in the world directly communicate with your local network, you just created a security hole the size of Texas (and we all know everything is bigger in Texas).

Comment: Well this is all within the local network (nothing is going outside our firewall with this app.. sorry for not mentioning this before).  As I said before, the report viewer control on a different app I created is able to see all the printers from my client laptop.  So what is it doing that I'm missing?

Comment: Forget on which side of the firewall your app resides... Your code runs server side, the report viewer control is allowed access to your local printers (local to the client), your code only knows about printers local to the server because you haven't told it otherwise. All report viewers that I ever worked with, create a PDF server side and send that to the client for printing... If the server is in your network, why don't you install the same printer you have access to on your laptop for the server.

Comment: I've already done that as a work around (allowing a user to select a printer from a dropdownlist connected to the deployed windows 2012 server) for now but it's a maintenance hassle.  This app (and other apps I'll be doing in the future) will be used by various user's thru out my company's facility and there's probably over a hundred printers they have access to.  The simplest thing would be for my app to directly print to the default printer from their client PC.

Comment: The simplest thing would be to drop the requirement because you are going to spend a MASSIVE amount of time on a fairly trivial requirement. If you really want to go down this path, look here: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E454 which uses a custom control (your boss will have to pony up some cash). or go the "rough-it" route and display the content on screen somehow and write javascript to send it to the printer, possibly using `window.print()`

Comment: Also, this might help: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/4803/how-to-print-the-rdlc-report-directly-without-viewing

Comment: Or even this... http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Print-RDLC-Report-without-Print-Preview-using-JavaScript-in-ASPNet.aspx All of these are fairly clumsy "solutions" though.